# google map marker hover effect

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a some google map with marker:

```js
var locations = [
  {
    'name'    : 'Location 1',
    'adress'  : '215 West Girard Avenue 19123',
    'location':{
      'lat' : 39.9695601,
      'lon' : -75.1395161
    },
    'lable'   : '200',
    'prev'    : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489706920962-640fcad4b463?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=057570f4673903ff39658ee6ac17a66a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  },
  {
    'name'    : 'Location 2',
    'adress'  : '5360 Old York Road 19141',
    'location':{
      'lat' : 40.034038,
      'lon' : -75.145223
    },
    'lable'   : '30',
    'prev'    : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483519396903-1ef292f4974a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=594ae239b7e8e8ed17d447a9950adeb4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  },
  {
    'name'    : 'Location 3',
    'adress'  : '1350 W Girard Avenue 19123',
    'location':{
      'lat' : 39.9713524,
      'lon' : -75.1590360
    },
    'lable'   : '45',
    'prev'    : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520803703785-bfb8d67060b1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5101b3f0270554cf6224f12e70cb7fb9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  }
];

gmarkers = [];




function initialize() {

  var content = document.getElementById('iw');

  var lat = 39.9995601,
      lng = -75.1395161,
      latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);  

  var mapOptions = {           
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),           
    zoom: 12,           
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP         
  };

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);



  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    gmarkers[locations[i].name] =
      createMarker(
      new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].location.lat, locations[i].location.lon),
      locations[i].name + "<br>" + 
      locations[i].adress, 
      locations[i].lable
    );   

    
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 350
    });       
  }




  function createMarker(latlng, html, lable) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      icon: {
        // path: "M12 0c-5.522 0-10 4.395-10 9.815 0 5.505 4.375 9.268 10 14.185 5.625-4.917 10-8.68 10-14.185 0-5.42-4.478-9.815-10-9.815zm0 18c-4.419 0-8-3.582-8-8s3.581-8 8-8 8 3.582 8 8-3.581 8-8 8z",
        // fillColor: 'red',
        // fillOpacity: 1,
        // strokeWeight: 0,
        // scale: 1,
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
        encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(44,44),
        labelOrigin:  new google.maps.Point(22,18),
      },
      label: {
        text: lable,
        color: "#fff",
      }
    });


    marker.setOpacity(.75);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(html);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });

    return marker;
  }



}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
};


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);







$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


  var $this = $(this),
      loc = $this.data('location');

  // ----- Var 2 Wit wrap initialize function
  myclick(loc);

});


$('a').hover(
  function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        loc = $this.data('location');

    gmarkers[loc].setOpacity(1.0);

    gmarkers[loc].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage (
     'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
             encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="red" d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
           new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
           new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
           null,
           null
    ) );
  },
  function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        loc = $this.data('location');

    gmarkers[loc].setOpacity(.75);

    gmarkers[loc].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage (
     'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
             encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
           new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
           null,
           null,
           null 
    ) );
  }
);
```

```css
#map {         
  height: 500px;         
  width: 100%;         
  margin: 0 auto;       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en"></script>


<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 1">Location 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 2">Location 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 3">Location 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="map"></div>
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/LBqqrm)

I'm trying to implement a color change:

```
marker.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage (
        'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
                encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="blue" d="M12 0c-5.522 0-10 4.395-10 9.815 0 5.505 4.375 9.268 10 14.185 5.625-4.917 10-8.68 10-14.185 0-5.42-4.478-9.815-10-9.815zm0 18c-4.419 0-8-3.582-8-8s3.581-8 8-8 8 3.582 8 8-3.581 8-8 8z"/></svg>'),
           new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
           new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
           null,
           null
    ) );
```

But for some reason, when hovering, the icon is shifted.

If you use svg, then generally this code does not work.

**Question:** What are the code for implementing the marker effect, changing the color of the marker, the size of the marker, and if using svg for the marker (changing the fill marker)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the problem, but `MarkerImage` was deprecated in lieu of the anonymous object `Icon` long ago (it is no longer documented, but still works)

The issue is you aren't defining the normal icons and the on hover icons the same way (some are using the `Icon` definition, some are using `MarkerImage`).
If I make the definitions consistent, the anchor for the icons doesn't change.

```js
function initialize() {

  var content = document.getElementById('iw');

  var lat = 39.9995601,
    lng = -75.1395161,
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[locations[i].name] =
      createMarker(
        new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].location.lat, locations[i].location.lon),
        locations[i].name + "<br>" +
        locations[i].adress,
        locations[i].lable
      );
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 350
    });
  }
  function createMarker(latlng, html, lable) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
          encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(44, 44),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(22, 18),
      },
      label: {
        text: lable,
        color: "#fff",
      }
    });
    marker.setOpacity(.75);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(html);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });
    return marker;
  }
}
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    loc = $this.data('location');
  // ----- Var 2 Wit wrap initialize function
  myclick(loc);
});
$('a').hover(
  function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      loc = $this.data('location');
    gmarkers[loc].setOpacity(1.0);
    gmarkers[loc].setIcon({
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
        encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="red" d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(44, 44),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(22, 18),
    })
  },
  function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      loc = $this.data('location');
    gmarkers[loc].setOpacity(.75);
    gmarkers[loc].setIcon({
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
        encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 4.198 3.469 9.21 8 16.398 4.531-7.188 8-12.2 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(44, 44),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(44, 44),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(22, 18),
    });
  }
);

var locations = [{
    'name': 'Location 1',
    'adress': '215 West Girard Avenue 19123',
    'location': {
      'lat': 39.9695601,
      'lon': -75.1395161
    },
    'lable': '200',
    'prev': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489706920962-640fcad4b463?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=057570f4673903ff39658ee6ac17a66a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  },
  {
    'name': 'Location 2',
    'adress': '5360 Old York Road 19141',
    'location': {
      'lat': 40.034038,
      'lon': -75.145223
    },
    'lable': '30',
    'prev': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483519396903-1ef292f4974a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=594ae239b7e8e8ed17d447a9950adeb4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  },
  {
    'name': 'Location 3',
    'adress': '1350 W Girard Avenue 19123',
    'location': {
      'lat': 39.9713524,
      'lon': -75.1590360
    },
    'lable': '45',
    'prev': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520803703785-bfb8d67060b1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5101b3f0270554cf6224f12e70cb7fb9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60',
  }
];
gmarkers = [];
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>


<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 1">Location 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 2">Location 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-location="Location 3">Location 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="map"></div>
```